# ,net 3.5 project referencing 4.5 dll

Tags: .net, dll, reference

I have a project in .Net 3.5, created using VS2010, referencing Exchange 2010 dlls in 3.5 .

I have to make this project compatible with Exchange 2013 for which I need to reference Exchange 2013 dlls (like Microsoft.Exchange.Management.dll) which is built for 4.5 framework.

Can I use the same project targetting .Net 3.5 and refer the Exchange dll(s) of 4.5 framework using Visual Studio 2010.

And can I use VS 2010 targeting 4.5 framework or do I have to use Visual Studio 2012 only to create .Net Fx 4.5 assemblies.

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Gagan,

This can't be done logically as .net framework don't allow Forward compatibility.

However what you can do is 
You can try converting it to MSIL and recompiling it to 3.5.

But for your question that 3.5 supporting 4.0, its NO.