# adding .net 5.0 assembly to project VS2017 .Net 4.7

Tags: c#, .net

What would be possible solution?
I know there is no direct referencing because VS 2017 does not support 5.0.

Make project .net 5.0 to make as a COM object? Or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference a .net framework 4.5.1 assembly in a 4.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807351/reference-a-net-framework-4-5-1-assembly-in-a-4-0-project) and [.net 3.5 project referencing 4.5 dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264858/net-3-5-project-referencing-4-5-dll) and [How to reference framework 4.0 dll in project targetting 3.5 in VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747858/how-to-reference-framework-4-0-dll-in-project-targetting-3-5-in-vs2008)

Comment: Use 4.7.2 or later.  There are known issue with 4.7.0 and Core.  Using Net 4.7.2 or later you can target an other versions of Net.

Comment: Don't get VS version and Net Version confused.  VS is a front end application that supports multiple version of the Net Library.  Net is the libraries that are used to compile the application.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Do you mean that we can add a reference to a .NET 5 dll in a Framework 4.7.2 project under VS2017?

Comment: The version of VS doesn't matter.  The c# compiler works with source language so VS has little issues.  The link says you can target Core 5.0 from Net 4.8 (but 4.7.2 should still work).  You may need to recompile the Net 5 code because different version of Net/Core executables are not always compatible.

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 will allow to reference the assemblies are compiled as .NET5 in future versions.
VS2017 does not support it.